# HTML file dropper not working in IE7+

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've use [this piece of code](http://damien.antipa.at/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/jquery.filedrop.js) to create a file dropper.

But it is not working in IE7+.... Like usual....

I get the error

> SCRIPT5007: Unable to set value of the property 'value': object is null or undefined

Code on the line

> files = e.originalEvent.target.files || e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files;
>
> for(i = 0; i < files.length; i += 1){

How can I get this working?

I know I can check if files is undefined, but then nothing happends. I want the file to get dropped.

Comment: Define "IE". IE 10/Win? IE 6/Win? IE 7/WinPhone?

Comment: That particular line isn't supported in some versions of IE and there is no workaround for them other than not using it in those versions.

Comment: IE7+ don't run this line... Btw how to drop files with a phone?

Comment: @Bondye — You've tested in IE 7, IE 8, IE 9 and IE 10 then?

Comment: @Quentin Yes IE7 IE8, and IE9, not IE10...

Comment: I think it's very unlikely that that line of code is actually the one that triggers the error message you've reported.

Comment: Do you actually set the `data-value` attribute for your HTML elements?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Full support for the drag and drop API [does not appear in Internet Explorer until version 10](http://caniuse.com/#search=drag).

You will need to use feature detection to provide a sane fallback in earlier versions.

Comment: @Bondye Notice how the link says that < IE 10 is _partially_ supported